# Is it possible to connect a device to a pc so the pc display is on the device's screen?

Tags: hdmi

Well the thing is i broke my pc monitor so is it possible to connect  it using an hdmi so the display is on the device screen?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: Samsung note 3 android

Answer (score 2):

VNC should be the answer.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing):

> Virtual Network Computing (VNC) is a graphical desktop-sharing system that uses the Remote Frame Buffer protocol (RFB) to remotely control another computer. It transmits the keyboard and mouse events from one computer to another, relaying the graphical-screen updates back in the other direction, over a network.

With VNC, you can control another computer or a group of computers available on a local network.

The procedure is as follows:
Install [Real VNC server](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/) on your computer, and [Real VNC viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realvnc.viewer.android) on your Android tablet. Your computer and Android tablet should be connected to the same network; if you don't have a WiFi connection, you can use your mobile WiFi hotspot or USB tethering to connect your computer for which you needn't require mobile data pack.

For your HDMI solution, I believe your tablet support OTG functionality. Buy [HDMI adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BQVK2PU) and an OTG cable. I believe it should do the job.
I fear the HDMI streaming could go opposite, so VNC should be your choice as HDMI would drain the battery and you won't be able to charge your tablet in between.